# Batch file: check for multiple registry keys, create/change as needed then continue?

Tags: batch-file, registry

OK, I'm needing a batch command, (a `FOR` loop perhaps?), to check multiple registry entries for the existence for the `StateFlags0001` key.

If the key doesn't exist, create it and set its `value` to `0x2`.
If it does exist, ensure that its value is set to `0x2`.

I know I can do this the "long way" with some clever `IF` commands, but I'm wondering if it can be simplified drastically somehow.

Ultimately, I'm wanting the `cleanmgr /sagerun:1` command automated via batch so I can do away with the `cleanmgr /sageset:1` command because this batch is going to be sent to some friends and family who don't know much of anything about doing even basic tasks on computers.
It'll be much easier to have them run a batch file then it would be for me to walk them through the steps that come after/during the `cleanmgr sageset:1` command...

Before anyone asks, "Why not simply set everything in the `VolumeCaches` folder to what you need?", I've omitted several keys because I don't want them included in the cleanup process so that's not an option.

Of course, if it's easier to do the reverse of my request and OMIT them and run the loop on what remains (ie; the keys below) then, by all means, lets do it that way...

Here's the keys in question:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Downloaded Program Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Internet Cache Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Memory Dump Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Old ChkDsk Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Previous Installations" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Recycle Bin" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Setup Log Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\System error memory dump files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\System error minidump files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Setup Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Thumbnail Cache" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Upgrade Discarded Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting Archive Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting Queue Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting System Archive Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting System Queue Files" /v "StateFlags0001" | Find "0x2"
```

So, in a nutshell;

Check the above keys for `StateFlags0001`.
If exist, ensure a value of `0x2`.
If not exist, create it and set value to `0x2`.
Run `cleanmgr /sagerun:1`.
Exit.

As always, thanks for the enlightenment!!!;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you already suspected, `for` is your friend

begin with something like this...

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=4 tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\"') do (
  echo %%~na
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('REG QUERY "%%a" /v "StateFlags0001" 2^>^&1 ^| Find "0x2"') do (
    echo %%b
  )
)
```

and then change the `echo` commands with the appropiate handling of the keys

**EDIT1:**
I have edited a bit my code, to show you how to handle the key name.

1. Note the `skip=4` option to skip the first lines of the `REG QUERY` output;
2. and the `echo %%~na` to extract the key name in order to process it and conditionally execute the second `REG QUERY`

**EDIT2:**
the check of a string against a list of strings is a bit tricky in BAT files. Here is some code to get you started

initialize a variable to hold the keys you are interested in

```
set keys=Active Setup Temp Folders
set keys=!keys!,Downloaded Program Files
set keys=!keys!,Internet Cache Files
set keys=!keys!,Memory Dump Files
set keys=!keys!,Old ChkDsk Files
set keys=!keys!,Previous Installations
set keys=!keys!,Recycle Bin
set keys=!keys!,Setup Log Files
set keys=!keys!,System error memory dump files
set keys=!keys!,System error minidump files
set keys=!keys!,Temporary Files
set keys=!keys!,Office Setup Files
set keys=!keys!,Temporary Setup Files
set keys=!keys!,Thumbnail Cache
set keys=!keys!,Upgrade Discarded Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting Archive Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting Queue Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting System Archive Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting System Queue Files
set keys=!keys!,Recycle Bin
```

then, in the outer for loop, change the `echo` command to

```
  call :findkey %%~na
```

and add the code to proceed with when found

```
  if "!foundkey!" NEQ "" ( 
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('REG QUERY "%%a" /v "StateFlags0001" 2^>^&1 ^| Find "0x2"') do (
      echo %%b
```

then add the logic of parsing the list

```
:findkey
set keylist=!keys!
set foundkey=
:againlist
for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%k in ("!keylist!") do (
  if "%%k" NEQ "" ( 
    if /i "%*"=="%%k" (
      set foundkey=%%k
      goto :found
    )
  )
  if "%%l" NEQ "" (
      set keylist=%%l
      goto :againlist
  )
)
:found
goto :eof
```

remember to also add

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

at the beginning of the BAT file, as it is required for the appropiate variable expansion inside the `for` loops.

**EDIT3:**

a simpler find method

```
:findkey
set foundkey=
for %%k in (!keys!) do (
  set curkey=%%k
  set curkey=!curkey:_= !
  if /i "!curkey!"=="%*" (
    set foundkey=!curkey!
  )
) 
goto :eof
```

this simpler `for` requires !keys! to be separated by blanks, so you will need to prepare !keys! by substituting all blanks by underscores, and the commas by blanks.

```
set keys=!keys: =_!
set keys=!keys:,= !
```

now, putting all the pieces together,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set keys=Active Setup Temp Folders
set keys=!keys!,Downloaded Program Files
set keys=!keys!,Internet Cache Files
set keys=!keys!,Memory Dump Files
set keys=!keys!,Old ChkDsk Files
set keys=!keys!,Previous Installations
set keys=!keys!,Recycle Bin
set keys=!keys!,Setup Log Files
set keys=!keys!,System error memory dump files
set keys=!keys!,System error minidump files
set keys=!keys!,Temporary Files
set keys=!keys!,Temporary Setup Files
set keys=!keys!,Thumbnail Cache
set keys=!keys!,Upgrade Discarded Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting Archive Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting Queue Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting System Archive Files
set keys=!keys!,Windows Error Reporting System Queue Files
set keys=!keys: =_!
set keys=!keys:,= !

for /f "skip=4 tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\"') do (
  call :findkey %%~na
  if "!foundkey!" NEQ "" ( 
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('REG QUERY "%%a" /v "StateFlags0001" 2^>^&1 ^| Find "0x2"') do (
      echo %%b
    )
  )
)
goto :eof

:findkey
set foundkey=
for %%k in (!keys!) do (
  set curkey=%%k
  set curkey=!curkey:_= !
  if /i "!curkey!"=="%*" (
    set foundkey=!curkey!
  )
) 
goto :eof
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't your code simply add the key/value to ALL contained within the VolumeCaches folder? I'm not wanting that. I'm only looking to modify the keys you see above.

Comment: the code above does not "simply add" any key. You need to add your own key handling logic.

Comment: I have edited a bit my code, to show you how to handle the key name in your code. Note the `skip=4` option to skip the first lines of the `REG QUERY` output; and the echo `%%~na` to extract the key name in order to process it and conditionally execute the second `REG QUERY`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the explanation, your code does the trick.